# Append a comma or dash to an argument if content exists

Tags: php

I've created a custom page template that shows custom field values for an archive page. 
I'm having trouble appending a comma or dash to an argument so it only shows when the argument has content. 
My date argument is showing even when I there is no date being placed into the post_date.

Years with no posts that have content placed into the custom fields are showing as:

2017
- , ( 01/01/1970)

Posts with blank arguments (such as no author information in the authors custom field) are showing as:

Title Information - , Publisher Information ( 09/19/2017)

```
<div>
<h3><?php _e( '2018', 'template' ); ?></h3>                                                                      
   <ul>                                      
   <?php                                         
       $archive_posts = get_posts( array(                                        
       'post_status'=> 'publish',
       'year'  => '2018',                                        
    ) );

    foreach ( $archive_posts as $archive_post ) :                                    
        $post_link = get_post_meta( $archive_post->ID, 'news_link', true);                                   
        $post_title = get_post_meta( $archive_post->ID, 'title', true);                                         
        $post_author = get_post_meta( $archive_post->ID, 'authors', true);                                       
        $post_publisher = get_post_meta( $archive_post->ID, 'publisher', true);                                      
        $post_date = get_post_meta( $archive_post->ID, 'date', true);                                                                                        
        $new_date = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($post_date));
        ?>                                       
       <li>                                      
           <strong><a href="<?php echo $post_link ?>"> <?php echo $post_title ?> </a></strong> - <?php echo "$post_author ," ?> <?php echo $post_publisher ?> ( <?php echo $new_date ?>)                                         
       </li>


  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You are obviously not getting anything returned by `get_post_meta( $archive_post->ID, 'date', true);` so I think in that case `$post_date` will be an empty string. Which explains why you get the unix start of time date. So test what comes back in `$post_date` before blindly using it in a `date()` function

Comment: It could be explained if you are using the wrong name for the meta fields as well

Comment: [The manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)